# AES_DECRYPT returns "Array" instead of decrypted data

Tags: php, mysqli, aes, encryption

I am trying to use AES_DECRYPT in MySQL to decrypt a successfully encrypted SSN. In the output I get the word "Array" instead of the actual data from that field. My PHP and MySQL knowledge is a bit rusty, so I'm sure it's something silly I overlooked. Any help would be appreciated.

OUTPUT:
verify_name other_names ssn dob
: test  : test  : Array : test

CODE:

`$key="88b871WZ3SntWK67rN3l2J1SvMqsOjyk";

$SQLstring = "SELECT * FROM applications";

            $QueryResult = @mysql_query($SQLstring, $conn) or die("Query Problem  - "

            . mysql_error($conn) . " - Error Number - " 

            . mysql_errno($conn));

            echo "verify_name other_names ssn dob"; 


            $num_result = mysql_num_rows($QueryResult);

for ($i = 0; $i < $num_result; $i++)


            {

                $row = mysql_fetch_array($QueryResult);

                    $SQLstring2 = "SELECT AES_DECRYPT(ssn,'$key') FROM applications WHERE name='" . $row["name"] . "'";

                    $QueryResult2 = @mysql_query($SQLstring2, $conn) or die("Query Problem  - "

                        . mysql_error($conn) . " - Error Number - " 
                        . mysql_errno($conn));

                    $num_result2 = mysql_num_rows($QueryResult2);

                    for ($j = 0; $j < $num_result; $j++){

                    $ssndecrypt = mysql_fetch_array($QueryResult2);


                    echo $ssndecrypt[0];

                    }
                echo $row["verify_name"]; 

                echo $row["other_names"]; 

                echo $ssndecrypt; 

                echo $row["dob"];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're fetching the result as an array.

```
$ssndecrypt = mysql_fetch_array($QueryResult2);
...
echo $ssndecrypt;
```

It's echoing `Array` because you never reassign the `$ssndecrypt` variable.

The core of the problem, however, seems to be that you're needlessly complicating your queries. There's no reason to query the table twice when you can just do:

```
SELECT verify_name,
       other_names,
       dob,
       AES_DECRYPT(ssn,'$key') AS ssn
  FROM applications
```

This simplifies the code quite a bit:

```
$stmt = "SELECT verify_name, other_names, dob, AES_DECRYPT(ssn,'$key') AS ssn FROM applications";
$result = @mysql_query($stmt, $conn) or die("Query Problem - " . mysql_error($conn) . " - Error Number - " . mysql_errno($conn));
echo "verify_name other_names ssn dob";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo $row["verify_name"];
    echo $row["other_names"];
    echo $row["ssn"];
    echo $row["dob"];
}
```

---

Ideally, though, you should be using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/book.pdo.php) instead of the `mysql_*` functions:

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb', $user, $pass);
    foreach($dbh->query("SELECT verify_name, other_names, dob, AES_DECRYPT(ssn,'$key') AS ssn FROM applications") as $row) {
        echo $row["verify_name"];
        echo $row["other_names"];
        echo $row["ssn"];
        echo $row["dob"];
    }
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) { die("ERROR: " . $e->getMessage()); }
```

Comment: so instead of mysql_fetch_array() what should I be using? Forgive my ignorance- I've never only had one result to grab before.

Comment: @kaitlynjanine: `mysql_fetch_array()` isn't necessarily the *wrong* approach, you just have to code in a way that properly uses the result. Changing your `echo $ssndecrypt[0];` line to `$ssndecrypt = $ssndecrypt[0]';` would probably work too, but it's less readable and a bit more "dangerous".

Comment: `for ($i = 0; $i < $num_result; $i++) 
   {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($QueryResult);
          
     $SQLstring2 = "SELECT AES_DECRYPT(ssn, '$key') AS decrypted FROM applications WHERE name='" . $row['name'] . "'";
     $QueryResult2 = @mysql_query($SQLstring2, $conn) or die("...");
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($QueryResult2))
     {
      $ssndecrypt = $row['decrypted'];
     } echo "all other fields echoed here-- there are 200 of them";
    echo $ssndecrypt;}` But the new code wipes all of my output. Did I get it wrong?

Comment: I've also tried `$SQLstring2 = "SELECT AES_DECRYPT(ssn,'$key') AS 'decrypt' FROM applications WHERE email='" . $row["email"] . "'";
     $QueryResult2 = @mysql_query($SQLstring2, $conn) or die("Query Problem  - "
      . mysql_error($conn) . " - Error Number - " 
      . mysql_errno($conn));
     $num_result2 = mysql_num_rows($QueryResult2);
     $result = mysql_query($SQLstring2, $conn) or die("Query Problem");
     $ssndecrypt = mysql_result($result,0);
     echo $ssndecrypt;` and the output for SSN is blank instead of the array.

Comment: @kaitlynjanine: After re-reading your original question, I think you're taking the wrong approach. See edited answer.

Comment: Ok, I changed the query as you suggested to (some fields removed) `$SQLstring = "SELECT name, address, city, state, zip, homephone, cellphone, position, shift, workedherebefore, previousemploymentdate, referred, empname, under18, friends, empname2, currentlyemployed, contactemployer, lawful, worktime, workweekends, dateavailable, desiredsalary, disclosuresig, verify_name, dob, AES_DECRYPT(ssn,'$key') AS ssn FROM applications";` and my output echos all of those fields, and I changed the output for ssn to `$row['ssn']` but nothing still shows up in the ssn field. It's the only blank field.

Comment: If you're getting an empty result for the `ssn` field, then `AES_DECRYPT` is probably failing and returning NULL. Are you sure the SSN is being successfully decrypted?

Comment: Thanks. Because it was a different issue (that seemed to be a common problem while searching the internet), I posted a new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713912/mysql-query-returns-blank-field-with-aes-encrypt

I am new to AES_DECRYPT() and I didn't realize the field had to be binary. Changing from varchar to blob fixed that issue.