# MySQL Query Returns Blank Field with AES_ENCRYPT

Tags: php, mysql, aes, encryption

My query string is `$SQLstring = "SELECT name, address, city, state, zip, homephone, cellphone, position, shift, status, workedherebefore, previousemploymentdate, referred, empname, under18, friends, empname2,  currentlyemployed, contactemployer, lawful, worktime, workweekends, dateavailable, desiredsalary,  position1, from1, to1, duties1, company1, cophone1, startsalary, endsalary, reasonleaving1, supervisor1, contact1, position2, from2, to2, duties2, company2, cophone2, startsalary2, 
 endsalary2, reasonleaving2, supervisor2, contact2, position3, from3, to3, duties3, company3,  cophone3, startsalary3, endsalary3, reasonleaving3, supervisor3, contact3, comments, training,  otherqual, documents, dltype, dlstate, expdate, yearsdriving,  movingviolations, hsname, hscity,  hsstate, hsdates,  collegename, collegecity, collegestate, collegedates, othername,  othercity,  otherstate, otherdates, licenseorcert, refname1, refbusiness1, reftitle1, refaddress1, refphone1,  refname2, refbusiness2, reftitle2, refaddress2, refphone2, refname3, refbusiness3, reftitle3,  refaddress3, refphone3,felony, iffelony, fired, iffired, resident, explanation, signed, q1, q2, q3,  q4, mq1, mq2, mq3, mq4, mq5, mq6, mq7, mq8, mq9, mq10, mq11, mq12, mq13, mq14, mq15, mq16,
 mq17, mq18, mq19, mq20, mq21, mq22, mq23, mq24, mq24b, mq25, mq25b, mq26, mq27a, mq27b, mq27c,  mq28, mq29, mq30answer, disclosuresig, verify_name, other_names, dob, AES_DECRYPT(ssn,'$key') AS ssn FROM applications";`

I query the results and then return them in a table. All of them work except for the AES_DECRYPT field (ssn). In the database it seems to have been encrypted fine, but this field in the query is returned as blank. Here is the rest of the code, just in case it's relevant:

`$key="88b871WZ3SntWK67rN3l2J1SvMqsOjyk";

$QueryResult = @mysql_query($SQLstring, $conn) or die("Query Problem  - "
            . mysql_error($conn) . " - Error Number - " 
            . mysql_errno($conn));`

```
        $num_result = mysql_num_rows($QueryResult);

        echo "<table>";

        for ($i = 0; $i < $num_result; $i++)    
        {
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($QueryResult);


            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["name"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["email"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["address"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["city"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["state"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["zip"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["homephone"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["cellphone"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["position"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["shift"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["status"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["workedherebefore"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["previousemploymentdate"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["referred"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["empname"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["under18"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["friends"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["empname2"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["currentlyemployed"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["contactemployer"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["lawful"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["worktime"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["workweekends"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["dateavailable"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["desiredsalary"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["position1"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["from1"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["to1"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["duties1"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["company1"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["cophone1"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["startsalary"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["endsalary"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["reasonleaving1"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["supervisor1"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["contact1"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["position2"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["from2"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["to2"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["duties2"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["company2"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["cophone2"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["startsalary2"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["endsalary2"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["reasonleaving2"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["supervisor2"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["contact2"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["position3"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["from3"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["to3"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["duties3"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["company3"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["cophone3"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["startsalary3"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["endsalary3"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["reasonleaving3"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["supervisor3"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["contact3"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["comments"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["training"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["otherqual"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["documents"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["dltype"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["dlstate"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["expdate"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["yearsdriving"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["movingviolations"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["hsname"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["hscity"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["hsstate"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["hsdates"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["collegename"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["collegecity"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["collegestate"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["collegedates"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["othername"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["othercity"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["otherstate"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["otherdates"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["licenseorcert"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["refname1"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["refbusiness1"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["reftitle1"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["refaddress1"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["refphone1"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["refname2"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["refbusiness2"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["reftitle2"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["refaddress2"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["refphone2"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["refname3"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["refbusiness3"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["reftitle3"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["refaddress3"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["refphone3,felony"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["iffelony"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["fired"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["iffired"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["resident"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["explanation"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["signed"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["q1"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["q2"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["q3"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["q4"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["mq1"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["mq2"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["mq3"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["mq4"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["mq5"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["mq6"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["mq7"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["mq8"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["mq9"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["mq10"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["mq11"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["mq12"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["mq13"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["mq14"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["mq15"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["mq16"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["mq17"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["mq18"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["mq19"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["mq20"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["mq21"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["mq22"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["mq23"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["mq24"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["mq24b"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["mq25"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["mq25b"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["mq26"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["mq27a"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["mq27b"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["mq27c"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["mq28"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["mq29"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["mq30answer"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["disclosuresig"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["verify_name"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["other_names"] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row['ssn'] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row["dob"] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure `$key` is defined?

Comment: Sorry, it is. I'll edit my original post with that info. This file has 300 lines of code so far - I just tried to pick the relevant lines and forgot that one :)

Comment: `foreach($row as $k => $val) { echo "<td>$val</td>"; }` can delete ~150 of them

Comment: omg THANK YOU! That is awesome. I will change that as soon as the code I have works. You rock!

Comment: that looks like you're defining $key after having tried to use it - i.e. the query has '' as the key since it's undefined. Put `$key = ` before `$SQLstring = `. This isn't a question for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use AES_ENCRYPT and AES_DECRYPT the field type must be BLOB. I had it set to VARCHAR and it wasn't recognizing some of the characters. Changing the field type to blob worked perfectly.

Comment: Tried to insert email with BLOB and in phpMyAdmin see something like hyperlink [BLOB - 32 B]. Changed to varbinary and see like 8a5928200c470cc63ed10b02fa62735d. So my conclusion is that column must be varbinary .

Comment: 0
down vote
 

Yes it works, I changed my varchar field to blob and it works ;) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL AES_DECRYPT() returns NULL if detects invalid data.
So the strings passed to the AES_DECRYPT() are invalid.
In this type of cases, I recommend to ECHO/alert the query so that you can see everything is right. The most probable mistake is what AD7six noted... the $key is probably empty.

```
$key="88b871WZ3SntWK67rN3l2J1SvMqsOjyk";
$SQLstring = "SELECT * FROM table"; // Replace with your Query
echo $SQLstring;
$QueryResult = @mysql_query($SQLstring, $conn) or die("Query Problem - " . mysql_error($conn) . " - Error Number - " . mysql_errno($conn));
```

Alerter:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
alert($SQLstring);
</script>";
```

I also recommend you read about [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: The key isn't empty (I had updated the question to reflect that). But I hadn't thought about the query being wrong. When I don't use the AES_DECRYPT function everything is fine, so I'll have to try what you suggested. I'll post my results in the morning.

Comment: The output is exactly as I expected. It echos as AES_DECRYPT(ssn,'88b871WZ3SntWK67rN3l2J1SvMqsOjyk') AS ssn FROM applications

Comment: My fieldtype is varchar. Should it be blob?

Comment: Yes! I'm sorry... I thought you knew...
AES_ENCRYPT() encrypts a string and returns a binary string.
Also, that means that your "ssn" field had the invalid text and that was what generated your symptom.

Comment: Also, I guess you could go for VARBINARY insted of blob... blob is the equivalent to TEXT for binary... and for a limited value like yours, it should prove to be more versatile.